# Is there a library to follow a sequence of indexing and `getattr` operations?

Tags: python, getattr

I have a bunch of objects, they have members, their members have members, ..., somewhere I need to do indexing, and then access members ...

So, basically, I want to get `obj.member1.member2[3].member4` and I also want to assign `obj.member1[2].member3.member4 = new_value`. I want to generate these "paths" which describe when to use `getattr` and when to use indexing dynamically. Is there a library for this? I imagine interface like

```
get_obj_path(obj, (("member1", "a"), ("member2", "a"), (3, "i"), ("member4", "a")))
```

and

```
assign_obj_path(obj, (("member1", "a"), (2, "i"), ("member3", "a"), ("member4", "a")), new_value)
```

Comment: Reinventing [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

Comment: It should not be hard to implement this.

Comment: @CrabMan ok, post some sample `obj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement those functions yourself:

```
def get_obj_path(obj, path):
    if not path:
        return obj
    (key, kind), *path = path
    if kind == "a":
        obj = getattr(obj, key)
    elif kind == "i":
        obj = obj[key]
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"invalid kind '{kind}'.")
    return get_obj_path(obj, path)

def assign_obj_path(obj, path, value):
    (key, kind), *path = path
    if not path:
        if kind == "a":
            setattr(obj, key, value)
        elif kind == "i":
            obj[key] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"invalid kind '{kind}'.")
    else:
        if kind == "a":
            obj = getattr(obj, key)
        elif kind == "i":
            obj = obj[key]
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"invalid kind '{kind}'.")
        assign_obj_path(obj, path, value)

# Test
class MyClass: pass
obj1 = MyClass()
obj1.i = 1
obj2 = MyClass()
obj2.lst = [obj1]
assign_obj_path(obj2, (("lst", "a"), (0, "i"), ("i", "a")), 2)
print(get_obj_path(obj2, (("lst", "a"), (0, "i"), ("i", "a"))))
# 2
```

Comment: this is just a flood

Comment: @user8426627 Not sure what you mean. Is that something good or bad?

Comment: i am doing the same with 4 lines, you have a flood over >20 lines with unessesary parameter "a" and "i". Also you should not produce your own exception without nessesarity

Comment: @user8426627 Because that is what the OP asked for. There is no "own exception", it is an standard exception, and it makes sense to use it when given parameters are wrong.

Comment: you could at least map function to "a" and "i"

Comment: @user8426627 Not sure what you mean but feel free to implement your own approach in your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified your solution to my taste a little bit but basically this is what I am gonna use.